# Aging from inception until forming of reproductive elements

Tags: senescence

Aging from inception until forming of reproductive construct.
For example, it takes two months for Spermatogonia to develop.
Why is DNA damage over generations not accumulated?

I have this study.
https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.03.11.435028v1.full
Is that consensus on the subject?

Comment: Somewhat relevant are the answers to these questions: [Is each generation getting older?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/), and [How are new people created from the DNA of an aged person](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/), and [DNA damage theory of aging and sex](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/94841/).  Also related: [Why doesn't mitochondrial DNA accumulate damage over successive generations?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/32978/).

Comment: Excellent ansert/comment. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are new people created from the DNA of an aged person. i.e. Why are we young?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/how-are-new-people-created-from-the-dna-of-an-aged-person-i-e-why-are-we-young)